# If you follow me, you might end up dead

Tags: riddle

> You would throw me when you need me most
>   You are certain to recover me when you don't
>   I usually point to a direction, yet I am not an arrow
>   I am not a road sign, and you wouldn't like to follow.

What am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're a

> **Ship's anchor**

You would throw me when you need me most

> When you need to anchor a ship is when you drop the anchor

You are certain to recover me when you don't

> And when the ship is to set sail, you don't need the ship to be anchored any more, so you recover (pull up) the anchor

I usually point to a direction, yet I am not an arrow

> Anchors are pointed at the end, they resemble but are not an arrow

I am not a road sign, and you wouldn't like to follow.

> You wouldn't want to follow an anchor down to the depths!

Title: If you follow me, you might end up dead

> Yep, dead by drowning. Sleep with the fishes.

Comment: Lnee! Avpryl qbar! Lnee!

Comment: @Saeïdryl - expanded on it a bit, hope that clarifies? The 'when you don't' contrasts with the 'need me most' of the previous line, not the word 'recover' (in case that was your point of confusion).

Comment: @Phylyp Yes perfect, I didn't make a link with the previous sentence :)

Answer (score 3):

I would say

> distress rocket 
>  You would throw me when you need me most => of course, you throw a distress rocket when you are in distress 
>  You are certain to recover me when you don't => You can see the distress rocket in the sky way better when you are far from the launch point and not just behind, i.e. when you are rescued 
>  I usually point to a direction, yet I am not an arrow => Distress rocket point where you are 
>  I am not a road sign, and you wouldn't like to follow. => Why would you want to follow something that is up in the sky?

Comment: Interesting though, but do you really recover that thing itself?

Comment: not really, Phylyp answer is better